# Error when calling Html.Partial("LogOnPartial") in template MVC 3 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

Everything works fine out of the box, but after adding a new controller that returns a strongly typed view using the model 'MySite.Models.Cars', i get the an error when calling Html.Partial("LogOnPartial") in SiteLayout.cshtml. I call the new view like this:

```
return View(db.Cars.FirstOrDefault());
```

This is the error:

> The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is of type
>   'MySite.Models.Cars', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of
>   type 'MySite.Models.LogOnModel'.

Very frustrating. When i use the new view without supplying a model it works again.

```
return View();
```

I setup the exact same conditions in MVC 2/ASPX and it worked just fine. I am not sure whether this is an MVC 2/MVC 3 or ASPX/Razor issue. In fact it might be a late night issue...

Very thankful for any reply.

EDIT:

First line from LogOnPartial.cshtml (i removed the underscore)

```
@model MySite.Models.LogOnModel
```

First line from Index.cshtml (new view):

```
@model MySite.Models.Cars
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `_LogOnModel.cshtml` partial as created by the template is not strongly typed and doesn't require any model. If you modified it so that it requires a model you will need to pass this model when calling it:

```
@Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial", SomeLogonModelInstance)
```

Comment: Ouch...i accidentally made it strongly typed. It is getting really late. You get the answer, looks like you could use a few extra points ;)

Answer (score 0):

Post the code from your View. (atleast the first few lines). Your view is expecting a Model of a certain type (LogOnModel) but you're passing in a different type (Cars).

You should see this LogOnModel referenced in the first line of your View. If you see the error, go ahead and fix it, if not post back here with a copy of your view and we'll help you out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though it might be a late night issue. What is the type of the partial? From what the error reads it seems as though you are passing in a Model type of Cars when the partial is looking for a Model of LogOn. This could have been something that was automatically created when you created the Partial.

Comment: LateNightIssue==true. I messed with the partial view earlier that day and made it strongly typed for whatever reason. I removed the code i added to the view but forgot the first line.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using Custom Membership and a partial view (_LogOnPartial) in _Layout page. By default _Layout page does not have a controller so don't use any model on it if is not necessary. Put your LogOnModel out of the _Layout page and let LogOff and LogOn ActionLikns remain on _LogOnPartial just like EF default membership approach.